# Disable Automatic Emails upon Task Assignment

Tags: email, tasks, task-list, sharepoint-email, workflow-tasks-list

I've developed a workflow in SPD 13 that assigns tasks to multiple users.

Each time the workflow runs, these users get an email that they have been assigned a task.

I do not want to send these emails. I've turned off the "send email when task is assigned" within my online SharePoint site, but the emails are still sent. I don't see an option within SPD to change this either:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a "WaiveAssignmentEmail" variable that you can set to "Yes" and it won't send out emails when the task is assigned.

[image]

[image]